# how can i find color code of pixel from android Bitmap Image

Tags: android

i am trying to find the color code from the Bitmap Image and i also try to get  that match color code pixel point my code is.

```
Point localPoint = new Point();
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
            int c = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            if (c == model.ColorCode) {
                localPoint.set(x, y);
                System.out.println("=== match");
                return localPoint;
            } else {
                System.out.println("=== " + c + ": \t : " + x + ": \t : " + y);
            }
        }
    }
    return localPoint;
```

the above code is work perfectly for the small image height and width but i have large image that's why it's getting long processing time.  please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html).

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {

            @Override

            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                int mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
                // Returns a muted color from the palette as an RGB packed int.
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the response, can i use this code in all API level ?

Comment: yes. to use, add 
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.1' to your bradle build

Comment: How does palette help me find a pixel position of a supplied color?

Comment: Well, Palette just answered the part of finding color code from an image. Truth is Palette implementation does this asynchronously. You could use your implementation, but i suggest you remove it from the main thread and run it asynchronously if so keen on getting pixel point.

Comment: OK, i got-it your point of view there is a one more problem here can i also get that pixel point on screen in your code, as you see in my code i found the pixel point on screen where the color code is find

Comment: If you did want to do that, you can do it the way you are trying to, but asynchronously, add a callback that would return the point and color code  if you want.